# Problem with mounting home partitions

Tags: fstab

I have a system running with an SSD as the drive with the operating system on it and a second hard disk which I want to use as the Home directories of the two users who will be logging in.

Much effort has led to the following `/etc/fstab` file which mounts user Liz with Home on the first partition of the second disk.

(Commented lines removed)

```
UUID=dd6197cb-bd27-4b48-9e54-e22f10ba8fee /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

UUID=1473881c-9d79-4b1f-b87c-969ea5ccc7b4 none            swap    sw              0       0

/dev/disk/by-uuid/e3852d06-ca3a-443b-9dca-f3fca010ee7d /mnt/e3852d06-ca3a-443b-9dca-f3fca010ee7d auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

/dev/disk/by-uuid/e7e7f622-7cb1-4de4-bf91-f336fa572c64 /mnt/e7e7f622-7cb1-4de4-bf91-f336fa572c64 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

UUID=e3852d06-ca3a-443b-9dca-f3fca010ee7d   /home/liz    ext4          defaults       0       2

UUID=e7e7f622-7cb1-4de4-bf91-f336fa572c64   /home/david    ext4          defaults       0       2
```

The second user however cannot log in with the final line of the file active. It stops with a permissions 644 error.

Both partitions mount in the `mnt` folder with root access only.

The two setups look identical to me so what can I do to fix it and let David use partition 2 of sda1 as `Home`?

Comment: Could you please add the output of `ls -l /mnt/e7e7f622-7cb1-4de4-bf91-f336fa572c64` to your question? Or even better, mount the partition manually and post the `ls -l` of its root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ravery for [his suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/a/935068/250300). 
I have made it work with the following commands in case it helps anyone else.

1. Created new user for John Doe username=john
2. Switch to John's account
3. ```
   gksudo gedit etc/fstab
   ```

   added to fstab:

   ```
   UUID=485f1719-3810-48ea-afa5-e64b082430d9 /media/johnpart ext4 defaults 0 2
   ```
4. ```
   gksudo mkdir /media/johnpart
   gksudo chown 1001:1001 /media/johnpart
   ```
5. Change permissions to create and delete for John and group John and apply to enclosed files
6. `sudo mount -a`
7. Copy John's files, including hidden, to the partition
8. ```
   cd /home
   sudo ln -s /media/johnpart
   sudo rm -r john
   sudo mv johnpart john
   ```
9. Reboot and it loads correctly with the data on the partition as Home.

Maybe overkill in places but it works.

Comment: yes this is as I had corrected my answer to ....  mounting the partition elsewhere then making a symlink to a writable folder.

Comment: I don't suppose you can help me with my other question above? - "Auto unmount USB drive on logout", can you?

Comment: which desktop are you using, well actually session manager, gdm, lightdm, kdm??

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have them mounted twice? Try just:

```
UUID=dd6197cb-bd27-4b48-9e54-e22f10ba8fee / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=1473881c-9d79-4b1f-b87c-969ea5ccc7b4 none swap sw 0 0
UUID=e3852d06-ca3a-443b-9dca-f3fca010ee7d /media/lizpart ext4 defaults 0 2
UUID=e7e7f622-7cb1-4de4-bf91-f336fa572c64 /media/davidpart ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Inside the partitions make a folder named Liz and David and set permissions as appropriate. And copy their files into the folders

Next, delete their folder from home, and replace with a symlink to the folders in their partitions.

Comment: Because if I didn't have the first mount instance, the first user had the same 644 error on login. Now she doesn't.

Comment: mounting twice will conflict, try the way I put

Comment: Will do, once I get home :-)

Comment: OK, got the message: 
Welcome to emergency mode
[    31.986396] EXT4-fs (sda1): Unrecognised mount option"uid=1000" or missing value
[    31.986994] EXT4-fs (sda2): Unrecognised mount option"uid=1001" or missing value

Copied the old fstab back in.
so what next?

Comment: try this method

Comment: What method? Nothing there, sorry

Comment: I edited the answer. mount the drive nd use simlinks to route their dirrectories

Comment: @ravery What is the advantage of symlinks instead of mounts?

Comment: @Melebius -- ext4  does not allow the setting of mount point ownership. so symlinking a folder inside the partition bypasses this limitation.

Comment: @ravery AFAIK this is not a problem – ext4 keeps information about permissions for contained files.The ability to set mount point ownership is useful for filesystems which do not manage ownership & permissions (FAT, NTFS etc.).

Comment: @Melebius - when mounting a partition directly to the users home folder via fstab, the folder's owner gets set to root which prevents the user from writing to it,  as the OP has stated .....  yes folders inside retain their permissions, that is why simlinking works.